# How to download Maps for Apple maps?

Tags: maps

How does one cache map data to enable GPS navigation without network access?  I would like to cache maps before visiting an island.

Comment: If you can consider using an alternative, HereWeGo maps app provide full offline capabilities. It can download maps data on a per country basis and allows you to navigate solely using device GPS.

Comment: Google maps also provides full offline capabilities now.

Answer (score 1):

iOS and macOS cache maps as you browse, so the first step is to visit all the places at the scales you wish so your system has a chance to cache the content.

I’m not aware of a way to force or pin these, so you might need a dedicated map if you have to be sure you have a complete offline map data.